# Limit import/export module to specific entity for an specific user group

Tags: magento-1.8, importexport

I want to allow an specific admin user group to import/export just products, but they can do the same for users too. What are the solutions for my problem?

The import/export default module of magento seems fine to me, I couldn't find any proper limitation for it.

Should I just create a new module or is there any module helping me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way in core itself to do it. You could create a custom module and either look at using observers to help control the acl and then setup the acl in your `system.xml` to just define the role. Otherwise you could look at downloading a 3rd party module to help with import/export there are lots out there!